# Is there a Mushroom Collector that will pay more than a Pokemon Center for Mushrooms and other 'gourmet foods'?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In Gen V there was a person that bought 'gourmet' ingredients like Tiny Mushrooms for a higher price than usual. Is there a person like that in Gen VI?

Comment: I don't think there is such a collector, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far from what I've been reading online on other message boards and from what I've seen on bulbapedia, there is no such collector. You might find this thread on [Rare Item Collectors](http://www.marriland.com/forums/pokemon-6th-generation/pokemon-x-y/448856-q-are-there-rare-item-collectors-in-x-y) helpful: